# Hide shop-by from left navigation on only one page

Tags: magento

We have a Brands page http://www.topdogdies.com/brands.html where our main 'categories' are 'Brands', but we also have a shop by Brands lower on the page, because we need that shop-by for our other tabs.

How can I hide the lower Brand shop-by from only this page in Magento?

Answer (score 0):

Each of this left column components are **blocks**. You can define which block should appear by layout (`*.xml`) files. You can find them in `/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/`. Usually you have to edit `catalog.xml` to load in the page the blocks you wish.

**This is a different case**. Both Product Type and Brand are under the same block. You have to edit `.phtml` files to fit your needs.
In `catalog.xml` you can find the load order of the blocks, and the path to their `.phtml` files (maybe catalog/navigation here). Look at the section of "Category with Anchor" of layout files (category pages with filters links), with `reference name="left"` (that is the left column).

**Track the right file** and place an `if` clause to skip the Brand section at this page (maybe while the page category id is equal to the Brand's id or - easier but worse - when the current url contains `brand.html`).

While **editing** a file, always work on a copy. Place your copy in `/app/design/frontend/default/YOURTHEMENAME/` and Magento will use the copy.